# $\int^{2\pi}_0 i\sin(x\sin \theta -n\theta) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, bessel-functions

I've read [this paper](https://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat415/lecture12.pdf) and I don't quite understand the reasoning at the end of page 3.

[image]

It seems like that $\int^{2\pi}_0 i\sin(x\sin \theta -n\theta) d\theta=0$, but why?

Comment: Because that integrand is odd about $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: Also worth pointing out: the definition of $J_n$ makes $J_n(x)$ real when $x$ is real, so of course the imaginary part must be zero!

Comment: Do you mean aside from: $J_n(x)$ satisfies a differential equation over the reals, so its imaginary component is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that inasmuch as $\sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta)$ is $2\pi$-periodic, we can write

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta)\,d\theta\tag1$$

Then, exploiting the fact that $\sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta)$ is an odd function of $\theta$, and the integration limits of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ are symmetrical around the origin, we conclude immediately that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x\sin(\theta)-n\theta)\,d\theta=0$$

And we are done!

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\sin(x\sin\theta-n\theta)$ is odd about the center of the interval:
\begin{align}
\sin(x\sin(2\pi-\theta)-n(2\pi-\theta))
&=
\sin(x\sin(-\theta)+n\theta -n2\pi)
\\&
=
\sin(-(x\sin\theta-n\theta) -n2\pi)\,,
\end{align}
and, since $n$ is an integer, $\sin(\phi+2 n\pi)=\sin(\phi)$, so,
\begin{align}
\sin(x\sin(2\pi-\theta)-n(2\pi-\theta))
=
-\sin(x\sin\theta-n\theta)\,.
\end{align}